# Blackberry - how to send email with attachment?

Tags: email, blackberry, email-attachments

In my application, I allow the user to create an image.  I then want to give the ability to email that image.  The concept is simple, but the execution is a bit more complex.

My first thought was to create my own email screen and send the email myself.  I understand how to accomplish this, but I don't like re-inventing the wheel and would like to reuse the blackberry's email functionality.

However, I am unsure about the capabilities of the blackberry and the best approach to take.  I'm looking for suggestions and comments on feasibility.

1) Take the image, save it on the handset, open up the email program and let the user send the email

2) save image on the handset, open up email program, programatically attach the image to an email and pre-populate the subject and body fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at these two documents:

1. [How To - Create an attachment](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800698/How_To_-_Create_an_Attachment.html?nodeid=800544&vernum=0)
2. [How To - Create and send messages](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800698/How_To_-_Create_and_send_messages.html?nodeid=1008283&vernum=0)

Comment: Those are excellent resources.  I'm wondering if it is possible to use the Messages application to send the attachment from my program.

The messages application is integrated with your contacts and has nice editing capabilities that I would prefer to not recreate.

Comment: Links seems to be outdated. [blank page]

Comment: @Mr_Green Since the question was answered nearly five years ago that isn't surprising. I'm sure the docuemnts are still there though since they apply to BBOS they are becoming less and less relevant.